# how can I run test files on Windows using rake?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, faker

UPDATE: when I run `rake test` from root, I get:

```
C:\workspace\faker>rake test
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -w -I"lib;test;." -I"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.r
b" "test/test_array_sample_method_compat.rb" "test/test_avatar.rb" "test/test_en_au_ocker_locale.rb" "test/test_en_ca_locale.rb" "test/test_en_locale.rb" "test/test_en_ug_locale.rb" "test/test_en_us_locale.rb" "test/test_es_l
ocale.rb" "test/test_faker.rb" "test/test_faker_app.rb" "test/test_faker_bitcoin.rb" "test/test_faker_book.rb" "test/test_faker_business.rb" "test/test_faker_city.rb" "test/test_faker_code.rb" "test/test_faker_color.rb" "test
/test_faker_commerce.rb" "test/test_faker_company.rb" "test/test_faker_date.rb" "test/test_faker_hacker_talk.rb" "test/test_faker_internet.rb" "test/test_faker_lorem.rb" "test/test_faker_name.rb" "test/test_faker_number.rb" "
test/test_faker_shakespear.rb" "test/test_faker_shakespeare.rb" "test/test_faker_slack_emoji.rb" "test/test_faker_street.rb" "test/test_faker_team.rb" "test/test_faker_time.rb" "test/test_faker_university.rb" "test/test_flexi
ble.rb" "test/test_helper.rb" "test/test_locale.rb" "test/test_pl_locale.rb" "test/test_uk_locale.rb"`
```

I don't fully understand what rake is doing at this point, but the system hangs infinitely. What am I missing?

So I have built some added functionality for the faker gem, and want to run the tests I wrote before submitting a pull request. However, all my attempts to run the existing tests, and my new tests, have failed. I am worried that it is a Windows machine related issue.

I have tried running `rake test:units` but it gives me an error and then hangs, while also ringing the Bell on my system 5 times. Strange right?

I have also tried running `bundle exec rspec spec`, but no tests are found becasue they are not RSpec unit tests, or at least not in the right location.

To see how the gem is formatted, check it out at [the repo](https://github.com/stympy/faker)

All the test files, including my new one, live in the `test` directory. But for the life of me, I can't run them.

Comment: it just hangs there, nothing after that output?

Comment: Yes. I let it hang for roughly 10 hours overnight even, no change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and works fine:

```
bundle install
bundle exec ruby test
```

Comment: `bundle install` works fine, but when I run `bunlde exec ruby test` from the root, I get `C:\workspace\faker>bundle exec ruby test
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
ruby: Is a directory -- test (LoadError)`

Comment: I've tried `C:\workspace\faker\tasks>bundle exec rake test`, but that has really strange behavior and results in the name of each test file being printed and then the system just hanging...